# Replace 0s with NA in tables

Tags: r, na

I generally work with dataframes and could easily do this for a data frame but on my current project I have the need to replace all zeros with NAs in a table structure.  For the following two tables (one using table and the other using ftable) how could I replace all zero counts with NA?

```
x <- with(mtcars,table(am, gear, cyl, vs))

x2 <- with(mtcars,ftable(am, gear, cyl, vs))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
x[x==0] <- NA
```